# How to create or update shopify fulfillments

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, fulfillment

I need to update/create shopify order fulfillment but getting some errors like
{
"errors": "Not Found"
}
I have checked creds everything is right key token store URL everything but getting this error again and again. is there someone who can help with this?

Code is copied and implemented from this guide [Fulfillments orders](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-10/resources/fulfillment#complete-2021-01)

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
define("API_KEY", '8f6ba81c2bXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define("ACCESS_TOKEN", 'XXXXXXXee88e7dXX3604d8XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
define("SHOP", 'myshopistore-XXXXX');
define("API_VERSION", '2022-10');

$ch = curl_init();
echo $url = 'https://'.API_KEY.':'.ACCESS_TOKEN.'@'.SHOP.'.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-10/fulfillments.json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
"{"fulfillment":{"message":"The package was shipped this morning.",
"notify_customer":false,"tracking_info":{"number":1562678,"url":"https://www.my-shipping-company.com","company":"my-shipping-company"},
"line_items_by_fulfillment_order":[{"fulfillment_order_id":125846255999999}]}}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: XXXXXX27eeXX8e7d9e3604dXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
print_r($headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Ensure your fulfillment order ID is correct. Without that, nothing will work. Your sample does not even try to look right, as it has to be a string with **gid** not just an integer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidLazar I have checked order id, it is correct. can you please tell me a bit more about where should I set a string (including gid instead of integer. I mean which value?

Comment: Are you using GraphQL?

Comment: Hey @DavidLazar I have fixed the problem. Thanks for your attention here.

Comment: Great. Let the community know what you had to do so as to ensure anyone else that does the same thing does not puzzle over it!

Comment: @DavidLazar Posted an answer mentioning how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of the question this can help someone in the same case, actually I was using wrong fulfillment_order_id and location_number
Before creating a fulfillment from above code we need to get the fulfillment_order_id from this API request **https://'.API_KEY.':'.ACCESS_TOKEN.'@'.SHOP.'.myshopify.com'/admin/api/2022-10/orders/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/fulfillment_orders.json**
this request will return the fulfillment_order_id inside the line_items node then use this id to create your fulfillment.

below API will return locations in case you need them
**https://'.API_KEY.':'.ACCESS_TOKEN.'@'.SHOP.'.myshopify.com'/admin/api/2022-10/locations.json**